# save and close all currently open excel sheets (python)

Tags: python, excel

I have another script that opens a bunch of excel sheets and exports a bunch of data to them. However, it is incapable of saving those documents automagically. Is there a way in python to grab all the currently open excel sheets, save them, and then close them?

Comment: ```pywin32``` is something you'll want to read up on (or ```comtypes```).  Unfortunately it won't be pretty

Answer (score 0):

What libraries are you using?

you can use

```
for each wb in xl.workbooks:
    wb.close(true)
```